# I'm working on a discord bot with slash commands, but it doesnt work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a discord bot(python) with slash commands for a school project, but every time I start the bot, it only give me an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ftfga\OneDrive\Documents\Arduino\drehdings\discordbot\slashtest.py", line 12, in <module>
    slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ftfga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py", line 59, in __init__
    self._discord.loop.create_task(self.sync_all_commands(delete_from_unused_guilds))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ftfga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 140, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(msg)
AttributeError: loop attribute cannot be accessed in non-async contexts. Consider using either an asynchronous main function and passing it to asyncio.run or using asynchronous initialisation hooks such as Client.setup_hook
```

the code is:

```
import discord
import serial
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)

slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)

ledstate = False

serport = serial.Serial("COM3", baudrate=9600, timeout=1)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user.name} is ready")

@slash.slash(name="led on", description="turn all LEDs on")
async def an(ctx):
    serport.write(b'a')
    await ctx.send("All LEDs we're turned on")


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I have no Idea how to resolve this problem

Comment: basically, the code is calling an async function from a sync function and this is not allowed...

Answer (score 0):

The `discord_slash` package is already very old and decpricated. It would be hard/impossible to make this work with current discord python version.

If you search for tutorials better look out for tuturials from this or last year.

A better way to create slash commands nowadays is to use @bot.tree.command.
First you have to make sure that your bot has the following permissions:

1. Send messages
2. Use Slash Commands

Here is an example:

```
import discord.ext
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix="!",intents=intents)
# sync the slash command to your server
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    synced=await bot.tree.sync()
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user.name}")
    print(len(synced))

# make the slash command that can be called with /meter and will write "Hello World!"

@bot.tree.command(name="meter",description="Mannu is a good boy")
async def meter(interaction:discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Hello World!")

bot.run(tokekeken)
```